# HttpHandler Not Found in Production

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, httphandler, web-config-transform

I am using an HttpHandler to dynamically determine the correct logo to show for a white-label site. This works perfectly when I run locally, but when we deploy the site to our test environment, calls to the HttpHandler return a 404.

I have a vague suspicion that this happening because of some sort of issue with the Web.config, for example, that the registration of the handler in the Web.config isn't making it to any environment outside local, so the handler isn't found. But there are no transforms between debug and release that should affect this, unless I need to actively do something to make sure the handler is registered across the various environment transforms (which I'm not currently doing).

Here's how the handler is registered in my Web.config (under `<configuration><system.webServer><handlers>`):

```
<add name="LogoHttpHandler" verb="*" path="imagehandler/*" type="MyWebApp.HttpHandlers.LogoHttpHandler, MyWebApp" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
```

I'll admit that I'm not entirely clear on what every piece of the above does (especially repetition of the namespace in the type param, and the resourceType param), but this was the code that worked. The file itself is in a root folder called Helpers-- I had thought it had to reside in App_Code, but this was causing namespacing issues and it ended up working without it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** The directions for registering a handler in IIS 7 in integrated mode begin: "Compile the HTTP handler class and copy the resulting assembly to the Bin folder under the application's root folder. -or- Put the source code for the handler into the application's App_Code folder." I have done neither of these things (as stated above, I began with my handler in App_Code but moved it out) and the handler still works in my local environment. Perhaps that's the true bug-- it shouldn't work anywhere, but is giving me a false positive locally?

Comment: It cannot be directly under <configuration>. Do you mean by <system.webServer>? Make sure on IIS your application pool runs under integrated mode, as <system.webServer> only works under that mode.

Comment: @Lex Li Yup, I missed that when copying it over. It is already under <system.webServer> and we're running in integrated mode. Thanks.